# Send wordpress form data to odoo for leads via post request

Tags: wordpress, odoo

I'm new to wordpress and would like to generate leads on odoo crm. I would like to send the form data in contact us form to odoo via a post request. I'm currently using wpforms plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

add_action(  'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'action__wpcf7_mail_sent'  );  

function action__wpcf7_mail_sent(  $contact_form  ) {

$title = $contact_form->title();
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();


if ( $submission ) {

    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
}

    function post_to_url( $url, $data ) {

        $fields = '';
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
            $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        }

        rtrim( $fields, '&' );
        $timeout = 30;
        $post = curl_init();  

        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt ($post, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt ($post, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0",rand(4,5)));
        curl_setopt ($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt ($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($fields));
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($post, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($post);

        curl_close($post);
    }

   if ( 'your contact form title' == $title ) {

    //you will get data in $posted_data variable
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($posted_data); 
    $data = $posted_data;

    $final_url = "your_api_url"; 
    post_to_url( $final_url, $data );

  }
}
```

try using this hook `wpcf7_mail_sent`

Comment: Where should I add it and also I have multiple forms using wpforms plugin. Also will this only work with contact form 7 or other wordpress forms plugin

Comment: You need to add this code in the fuctions.php file of your active theme. and You can differentiate form using this condition `if ( 'your contact form title' == $title ) {`

Comment: ok thanks. This will work in only contact form 7 or others too. As I check the hook is for contact form 7